# Java make methods static when possible, good practise?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, coding-style, static

I set my compiler to warn me about methods that could be made static.

These methods are mostly some helpers to do calculations, set attributes on passed objects and so on.

Should I make them static, or is this a sign that my coding style is city (CN)?

Comment: I don't think that there's any rule that you should make them all static or all not static. In my mind static should be used where it belongs -- methods that belong in the class rather than the instance such as utility methods, and not used where it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be wary of using static methods for things that you would like to abstract later. Static methods do not support swapping implementations because have a hard link between the consuming class and the implementation class.

That being said, I think there are still places where static methods are appropriate (Utility classes).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels nice nickname

Answer (score 2):

Generally utility methods and other things that belong to the class should be made static. Faced with a method that doesn't access instance state you should ask yourself though whether subclasses can reasonably override a method providing a state-dependent implementation before you make it static.

Answer (score 1):

All stateless utility classes should be made static. Gurus, correct me if I am wrong:  stateless static methods (no global/static variable usage) are thread safe!

Answer (score 1):

Making a method static can be good practice because you know that a static method doesn't need access to any instance data. For that reason, it also has a small performance boost.